# Resign effective immediatly after retraction

Tags: resignation, new-zealand

Retracted resignation after counter offer and now l realise its a mistake, how do l resign effective immediately?

Can my employer charge me for replacement?

I am based in New Zealand.

Comment: Just a few questions to help answer this: Which country are you in? Did you sign the new offer or just verbally say you accepted it? Does your new contract say anything about penalties for resigning within a timeperiod of accepting it? Do you simply want to terminate the employment or are you also trying to get a good reference? In what way are you worried the employer can charge you? (The likely answer is: "Just serve a new notice, and leave at the end of that period, as usual.")

Comment: I am located in NZ. No mention of any further terms other than what is already outlined in my contract. I havent actually signed it yet. Have another job offer. Did not gain refrences from current employer

Answer (score 3):

> how do l resign effective immediatly?

Well unless your counter-offer included some sort of minimum-time related bond (which I believe is possible in *some* jurisdictions) I doubt they can stop you resigning. In the majority of locales though it would be effectively considered a "new" resignation so any contractual or legal notice periods required would begin from that date rather than the earlier one. Of course some employers may *choose* not to enforce that aspect but bear in mind that they might not be feeling too kindly disposed to you given your, erm, *indecisiveness* so you might be best off just taking it on the chin without too much complaint.

> Can my employer charge me for replacement?

This would be an exceptionally rare possibility, unless your actually breaching a contractual term somewhere the costs of hiring a replacement are pretty much the employer's problem not yours.